# Is there's any python library to output dictionary in beautiful ascii table?

Tags: python, ascii

I have quite huge dictionary in here, which just repeats all over again, and I'm searching for any code to display that dictionary in some ascii table, which would be outputed to command line. At least to have some generated columns for non-dimentional dictionary, and the rest could go as a key:value in cells, something like this:

dictionary = {"column1":{"key":"val"}, "column2": "value" }

```
=====================
| column1 | column2 |
=====================
| key:val | value   |
```

it's still better then to see all those `u"" {} ,` in output which is really disturbs when I need that information fast.

Comment: Have you looked at `pprint`?  It's definitely not the format you describe, but it's probably nicer than what you're getting.

Comment: yes i did, using it now, it's ugly as hell i mean it's just dump of regular dictionary, same like json_dumps() does. nothing special in here. how can i create normal TUI.. something like ncurses does but more lightly just to output dictionary into table.. mysql cli client does the same actually..

Comment: this one does something like this, probably gona implement a reach dictionary support my self.. http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577202-render-tables-for-text-interface/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can use [`prettytable`](http://code.google.com/p/prettytable/wiki/Tutorial).

```
t = PrettyTable(['key', 'value'])
for key, val in dictionary.items():
   t.add_row([key, val])
print t
```

You can also play with [`textwrap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) module to split the value on multiple lines ([example in this gist](https://gist.github.com/dnozay/4965322)). Imagine you want to show the contents of os.environ; results (short version):

```
+------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|             key              |                            value                             |
+------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|            CFLAGS            |           -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall            |
|                              |    -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector    |
|                              | --param=ssp-buffer-size=4  -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE |
|                              |         -fPIC -fwrapv   -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall          |
|                              |    -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector    |
|                              | --param=ssp-buffer-size=4  -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE |
|                              |                        -fPIC -fwrapv                         |
|             MAIL             |                    /var/spool/mail/damien                    |
|          LS_COLORS           | rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=4 |
|                              | 0;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=3 |
|                              | 0;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;3 |
|                              | 1:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01; |
|                              | 31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:* |
|                              | .dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.tbz |
|                              | =01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm= |
|                              | 01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar= |
|                              | 01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=0 |
|                              | 1;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm= |
|                              | 01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm= |
|                              | 01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svg |
|                              | z=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mp |
|                              | eg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m |
|                              | 4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.w |
|                              | mv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.a |
|                              | vi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf |
|                              | =01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv |
|                              | =01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au= |
|                              | 01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp |
|                              | 3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa |
|                              | =01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:*.pdf=00;33:*.ps |
|                              | =00;33:*.ps.gz=00;33:*.txt=00;33:*.patch=00;33:*.diff=00;33: |
|                              | *.log=00;33:*.tex=00;33:*.xls=00;33:*.xlsx=00;33:*.ppt=00;33 |
|                              | :*.pptx=00;33:*.rtf=00;33:*.doc=00;33:*.docx=00;33:*.odt=00; |
|                              | 33:*.ods=00;33:*.odp=00;33:*.xml=00;33:*.epub=00;33:*.abw=00 |
|                              |   ;33:*.htm=00;33:*.html=00;33:*.shtml=00;33:*.wpd=00;33:    |
|       GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS       |                       JS ERROR;JS LOG                        |
+------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```